# Variations of the release starting

Tags: linux, erlang

There is an instruction at the cowboy application example:

https://github.com/extend/cowboy/tree/master/examples/hello_world

To start the release in the foreground:

```
$ ./_rel/bin/hello_world_example console
```

What is "console" parameter? Is it specific for Erlang or for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can investigate **hello_world_example** script in your release and will find out that **console** is specific parameter of this release startup script.

This parameter let you start your release in attached mode - with system console which could be useful for debugging, testing, etc. Alternative is detached mode - useful for running daemons and backgrounds processes - this probably will be your production mode.